# url in a address bar won't get changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am creating dynamic hyper links in a jquery mobile page based on a ajax response as follows

```
for( i = 0 ;i < data.length ; i ++)

       var links = "<a href="http://www.example.com/friend.html?id="+data[i].id+
                        "&name="+data[i].name+"</a>";
```

**but whenever a user clicks over this links the page appears but the url in a address bar 
doesn't get changed.**

for example , if above links are generated in a following page

```
http://www.example.com/myinfo.html?token=323423432&id=32332
```

then whenever user clicks over a dynamic links the new page appears but the address bar will have the same above `myinfo.html` url rather then `friend.html`

i tried to insert `data-ajax="false"` which deffinately changes the url in a address bar but the problem is when i click a back button on a `friend.html` page then `myinfo.html` page gets reload again `which i don't want`

back button in a friend.html is set as follows

```
  <a href="#"  id="friendinfo_back"  data-rel="back"   data-icon="back">Back</a>
```

and its href is being set dynamically which points back to myinfo.html with its previous token and id

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobiles uses AJAX loading of pages to give the user a smooth experience where pages transition into each other. This is done by loading the contents (`<body>`) of the target page, and loading it into the current page. This way they can make a smooth transition between pages and you don't actually leave the source pages, and you don't actually visit the destination page. That's why the URL in the address bar doesn't change.

Comment: well i am going out of the current page and loading a new one because i need to pass few values with query strings so that user wont find any difficulty when he reloads the page over here the page is friend.html

Comment: so sometimes only a single page HTML is not worth to handle all the operations thts why i am dividing it into multiple

Comment: You aren't actually going out of the current one. jQuery mobile pick's up all links and when a link is clicked, jQuery mobile handles it, instead of the browser. jQuery then makes an AJAX call to the provided URL and retrieves the content within the current page.

Comment: but the problem is when i refresh the page then the older one gets refreshed not the new one as in address bar the url dont get changed :(